# Embedding OpenGL, written using NDK, inside a Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-fragments, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on an educational game and I want the graphics part to be rendered with OpenGL, and NDK may be a better choice, but I am running into a problem with how I can make this work with Fragments.

Currently, if I just pass the fragment activity to GLSurfaceView it should work properly (I am still designing out everything), when I do OpenGL from Java, even though this is in a fragment.

I would like fragments so that on a tablet I can show all of the parts at one time, but on a phone the user will see equations on one screen and the results on another.

Is it possible to have my graphics be in a separate fragment and render the image with OpenGL, using NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall no obstacles why GLSurfaceView couldn't be part of Fragment's layout, same way it can be part of "regular" layout, however be aware you can have just one SurfaceView visible at the time. If you target API14 and up you can check [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) that acts as regular View (contrary to the way GLSurfaceView works).

Comment: I will try it, I am still trying to get NDK working properly on my computer. I realized that I need to create more fragments and have the SurfaceView in it's own, but have other fragments on the layout.

Comment: Your answer actually helped me with a problem on a different application (taking a picture and putting controls in), so I expect the same answer will work for my graphics issue. Thank you.